# когда той или иной таблицы нету то я добавляю ее, однако она дублируется и данные добавляется в новую. как это исправить?

Tags: python, sqlite, list, dict

вывод из таблицы с ошибкой `[{'rus': 'Обещанный Неверленд', 'count': 2}, {'rus': 'Обещанный Неверленд', 'count': 4}, {'rus': 'Ванпанчмен', 'count': 5}]`

```
def sql_fetch_stat_anime(con):
    
        cursorObj = con.cursor()
    
        cursorObj.execute(f'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM stat_name_anime')
        n_set = []
        rows = cursorObj.fetchall()
        for i in rows:
            rus,count = i
            n_set.append({"rus":rus,"count":count})
        return n_set
    
    
    def sql_upd_anime_stat(con, entities):
    
        cursorObj = con.cursor()
    
        cursorObj.execute('UPDATE stat_name_anime SET count = ? WHERE count = ? AND anime = ?', entities)
        con.commit()
    
def sql_insert_anime_stat(con, entities):

    cursorObj = con.cursor()

    cursorObj.execute('INSERT INTO stat_name_anime(anime, count) VALUES(?, ?)', entities)

    con.commit()
```

часть кода с взаимодействием

```
base_anime_stat = sql_fetch_stat_anime(sqlite3.connect('mydb_discord.db'))
        for i in base_anime_stat:
            rus,count = i["rus"],i["count"]
            if russian == rus:
                number = count + 1
                sql_upd_anime_stat(sqlite3.connect('mydb_discord.db'),(number, count,russian))
            else:
                sql_insert_anime_stat(sqlite3.connect('mydb_discord.db'),(russian,1))
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что `SELECT *` выдаёт вам поля в нужном порядке, например? Кстати, если у вас записи множатся, то как же счётчик прибавляется? Может у вас от предыдущих экспериментов лишние записи остались, например.

Comment: вроде как, да.я при проверке каждый раз удаляю таблицу.

Comment: Появляются дубликаты потому, что вы в цикле проходите по всем записям из БД и для каждой совпадающей записи, ее изменяете (тут проблем нет). А вот если встречается не совпадающая запись, то вы вставляете новую запись, **независимо от того, если запись з таким значением поля anime в БД**